# view slideshow not working

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I created a view block and a content type "slideshow image" with "title" and "image" specially for slideshow.
In this block only images of "slidshow image" content will appear.

And i added up five elements and i see effects on the slide show.

And even i created a directory named "jquery.cycle" in libraries
 \sites\all\sites\all\modules\libraries. Added the jquery.cycle.all.js file into that directory and but i didnt got any sliding of images...

Only the latest image is displaying but no effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the libraries API module, the correct place for the JS code is actually sites/all/libraries, not \sites\all\sites\all\modules\libraries (why do you have sites/all in the path twice?)

What slideshow module are you using, views_slideshow? I don't think you will actually need to add a jquery library if that is the module you are using, but that will depend on the actual module you are using. If you are trying to build a slideshow from scratch with jQuery cycle, here is info from the handbook on getting your js added to Drupal http://drupal.org/node/304255

Comment: technically, the code must live in **sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/** so it looks like **sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js** and I also made sure to have **sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.lite.js** this was set up for views_slideshow with views_slideshow_cycle enabled

Comment: @fndtn357 Did that but no slide effect and refresh all cache and theme flush.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you let me know how we make slideshow like in link http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html

Answer (score 0):

> Only the latest image is displaying but no effects.

Make sure the view returns more than one image.

Also, for views_slideshow module, make sure the display style is set to Slideshow and correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

download and install dev version of jquery_update module and change version 1.7 of jquery on settings page

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by unchecking the "Display all values in the same row" setting under the MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS for the image field I wanted to cycle through.